# Routing in Electron + Create React App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron, create-react-app

I used create react app and electron for a project. It works fine in dev environment.

[dev environment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJlwl.jpg)

However when i build the project and try to run it using electron i get a blank screen. i do not see any errors. i believe this has something to do with routing since electron uses file system.

[Image of my route file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tqj2.jpg)

How do i build the app and use react routing instead of file system ??

Answer (score 6):

Import HashRouter from react router instead of BrowserRouter. BrowserRouter requires a server to function, electron does not start a webserver instead it works directly with files.